# Prove that each matrix is invertible and find their inverses

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I have three $n\times n $ matrices $A,B,C$ and it is given that $ABC=I$, I should prove that each $A,B$ and $C$ are invertible and find their inverse.

Here is what I have: Since $ABC=I$ then I might have that $A$ and $B$ and $C$ are inverses of each other, but from this moment I got confused.

Comment: A matrix really has only one inverse. You know $ABC=I$, so how can you solve $AX=I$ for $X$?

Comment: duplicate? see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/850584/abc-i-implies-b-is-invertible-and-b-1-ca)

Comment: If at least one of the three matrices is not invertible, its deteminant is $0$ implying that the determinant of the product of the matrices is $0$. This contradicts $\det(ABC)=\det(I)=1$

Comment: Here is a hint to find $B^{-1}\cdots(ABC)^{-1} = C^{-1}B^{-1}A^{-1} = I^{-1} = I$

Answer (score 1):

$A$ is invertible because $BC$ is its inverse.

$C$ is invertible because $AB$ is its inverse.

$B=A^{-1}IC^{-1}$, a product of invertible matrices, and is therefore invertible. To find $B^{-1}$, we have $$B^{-1}=(A^{-1}C^{-1})^{-1}=CA$$

Answer (score 0):

Associativity gives $$I=A(BC)=(AB)C$$these should yield $A^{-1}$ and $C^{-1}$ pretty easily. What do you think we can do for $B^{-1}$ (hint: the previous part says $A$ and $C$ are invertible)?